# Reset class fragment extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have :

```
OneFragment.java (Class OneFragment extends Fragment )
TwoFragment.java (Class TwoFragment extends Fragment )
ThreeFragment.java (Class ThreeFragment extends Fragment )
FourFragment.java (Class FourFragment extends Fragment )
FiveFragment.java (Class FiveFragment extends Fragment )
```

All of above in a one activity named as "MainActivity"  and every of above items have 1 .xml layout.

I want restart `TwoFragment.java` , how can I do this ?

my main activiy code for create fragments :

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        //ino public kardam Bala hal shod
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "تماس با ما");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "نتایج");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ایجاد لینک");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "تنظیمات");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "سوالات");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DrawFromBackTransformer());

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        //ino public kardam Bala hal shod
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "تماس با ما");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "نتایج");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ایجاد لینک");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "تنظیمات");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "سوالات");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DrawFromBackTransformer());

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        //ino public kardam Bala hal shod
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "تماس با ما");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "نتایج");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ایجاد لینک");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "تنظیمات");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "سوالات");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DrawFromBackTransformer());

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        //ino public kardam Bala hal shod
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "تماس با ما");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "نتایج");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ایجاد لینک");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "تنظیمات");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "سوالات");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DrawFromBackTransformer());

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code here please.

Comment: Give more details, put your MainActivity code and explain what is this "restart"

Comment: main activity code added :) , my mean about "reset " is reload fully "twoFragment.java" x